# Как выбирать случайные точки только из тёмных участков изображения?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения

Есть ч/б картинка – какая-то залитая чёрным плоская фигура на белом фоне.

Создаю изображение такого же размера, где случайно расположеные точки набрасываются только там, где в исходной – чёрное.

Делаю это явно не оптимально: выбираю случайную точку исходной картинки, и смотрю, какой цвет в ней в исходной – если чёрный (или `яркость < X`), то эта точка мне подходит и в этих координатах в выходной картинке ставлю точку (на деле помещаю спрайт).

**Как можно оптимизировать/ускорить процесс**, чтобы не было холостых выстрелов, коих обычно большинство, т.к. фигура имеет площадь много меньшую, чем всё поле).

Comment: какие примерно размеры исходной картинки в пикселях?

Comment: 1080x1080 (инстаграм)

Comment: могу предложить тогда сделать список из тёмных (в вашем определении) клеток и выбирать уже из них. Клеток будет не больше миллиона, а с учётом что фигура меньше прямоугольника то и ещё меньше.

Comment: какого рода фигура? случайная или, допустим, прямоугольник? если часть черной фигуры не попадет в область набрасывается точек - это критично?

Comment: фигура – сложная: лого, рисунок, слово крупными буквами, число жирным шрифтом.

Comment: что значит "не оптимально"? Например, представьте что каждая десятая точка является "тёмной" на изображении, тогда чтобы выбрать случайную тёмную точку в среднем нужно только 10 раз пробовать в не зависимости от размера изображения. Сравните, к примеру, с алгоритмом, который перебирает 100_000 темных точек из 1000_000 точек изображения, и затем выбирает только из этих 100_000 темных точек кол-во операций ~1000_000 вместо 10. Второй алгоритм становится предпочтительным только если вы хотите значительную часть тёмных точек выбрать (~100_000).

Comment: Какое big O поведение вы ожидаете (N-все точки, M- только тёмные, К-сколько случайных надо)? Первый алгоритм `O(K*N/M)`,  второй алгоритм: `O(K+N)`. Если `K==1`, то явно первый алгоритм более предпочтительный. Если `K~N`, то второй алгоритм лучше для больших N, если `M<<N`

Answer (score 1):

В задаче очень много неизвестного.

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

1. Берем центральную линию и проверяем, есть ли на ней черная точка.
2. Если нет, то проверяем линии на 1/4 и 3/4
3. И т.д. деля следующий шаг пополам, пока не находим линию с черными точками.
4. Как нашли - принимаем ее за базовую и по такому же алгоритму ищем самую левую и самую правую линию, в которой точка еще есть и в качестве границы берем следующую за ней, на которой точки нет

Comment: спросите, что неизвестно в задаче. Есть работающее неэффективное решение – я его описал: просто тыкаются случайные точки во всей картинке, и в зависимости от цвета выбранного пикселя, принимается решение.

Comment: описанные действия позволяют найти и обойти чёрные точки сплошной фигуры, не имеющей островов, но зачем это?

Comment: @Sergiks Про островки в условия ни слова не было. "залитая чёрным плоская фигура" - это именно фигура, а не набор фигур. В случае небольшой сплошной фигуры данный метод отсеит довольно много ложных срабатываний. Если в вашем случае заливка может быть с разрывами и рассеяна по всей площади, то никакого другого алгоритма кроме как пулять наугад по всей картинке - нет. Ну либо действительно просканировать все точки и нужные собрать в массив, из которого выбирать, но, имхо, это будет сильно накладней.